# Can we setup multiple CNAME records pointing to Azure blob storage?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have already setup a CNAME for "storage.mycompany.com" pointing to my blob storage and it's working fine. However, I have a multitenant application and some of my customers would like their own personalized url. They would like "storage.customer1.com" to also point to the same blob storage.

One of my customers configured a CNAME in his DNS (let's say 'storage.xyz.com') pointing to my DNS entry 'storage.mycompany.com' but it didn't work.

Does anybody know it that's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work because the CNAME is how the storage subsystem knows which tenant to route to (it sees the CNAME).  So, without registering that CNAME with blob storage there is no way to tie the two together.

Comment: That's what I thought. I wish the answer was different though!

Comment: @dunnry is it possible to programmaticaly code the registering process to point to customer's domain.  ???

Comment: Not sure if it is active yet in this version of mgmt API, but splunking around the client assembly in the SDK tells me that there is an API for that on the way at a min.

Comment: It's been more than a year since I asked this question. Does anybody know if the situation has changed? Is it now possible to have multiple CNAMEs pointing at the same blob storage?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but in case anyone else stumbles across this looking for an answer...

If you don't mind spending a bit more money, you can create an Azure CDN for the blob storage. You can then map multiple CNAME records to this CDN endpoint.

If you'd like to see direct support for multiple CNAME records show your interest by voting for the suggestion here:
http://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/9026314-map-multiple-cname-records-to-blob-storage